# sublimeREPL for python not showing complete Traceback

Tags: windows, python-2.7, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm trying to run my python code using sublimeREPL's "Python - RUN current file" command

It works fine if my program has no problems, but when it does, it doesn't show the complete Traceback (I don't get to see the "Repl Closed" message), and the output its not even consistent. Below two runs of the exactly same file (not posting images because stackoverflow doesn't allows me to because I'm new):

First Run:

```
------- Ford Fulkerson -------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ford-Fulkerson.py", line 282, in <module>
    D = FordFulkersonGeneral(G, ['A'], ['E'], None, restricciones)
  File "Ford-Fulkerson.py", line 71, in FordFulk|
```

Second Run:

```
------- Ford Fulkerson -------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ford-Fulkerson.py", line 282, in <module>
    D = FordFulkersonGeneral(G, ['A'], ['E'
```

I was using the Anaconda's (64 bit) python distribution. Then I changed to a regular python (32 bit) install (made sure the window's path was all right) and even there its not working.

If I run my code from window's terminal I get the full Traceback (the actual error is not important, I know how to fix it):

```
------- Ford Fulkerson -------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ford-Fulkerson.py", line 282, in <module>
    D = FordFulkersonGeneral(G, ['A'], ['E'], None, restricciones)
  File "Ford-Fulkerson.py", line 71, in FordFulkersonGeneral
    G.deleteNode(v)
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Learning\Anßlisis de Re
des\Ford-Fulkerson\mvr_graph.py", line 196, in deleteNode
    self.nodes[node].delete(n)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

---

Edit:
I've found the answer by posting this question. The problem was in the path of the file - it contains an accent in the word "Análisis". I changed that and know its working.

It used to work when I had my OS language set to spanish. I set my new installation to english and now it was giving me trouble. I really didn't expected that, shame on you Windows x(.

I don't really know the protocol, I will just leave this question here in case anyone is going through this obscure thing.

Comment: If you've found the solution, please post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer by posting this question. The problem was in the path of the file - it contains an accent in the word "Análisis". I changed that and know its working.

It used to work when I had my OS language set to spanish. I set my new installation to english and now it was giving me troubles. I really didn't expected that, shame on you Windows x(.